# Display Image in website written in C# from url

Tags: c#, sql-server, search-engine

I am trying to create a website that can let user to search images.
I created a local database ( a folder with a few images) for image, and there are 3 columns for data: title, picURL and keyword.

At my default page, I set up a textbox and Search button. What I did is:

```
string query = "SELECT picURL FROM imagedatabase WHERE [keyword] = '" + keyword + "'";
```

[keyword] is one of the name of the column and the keyword is the one user types in the textbox.

So now if I find an image in the database, then I got its URL. But how can I display the image in .aspx? like are they any specific command or something I can do to display the image?

thanks

---

EDIT:

So I changed the code like this:

In my homepage.aspx, I added in this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Image1.ImageUrl" />
```

and in my homepage.aspx.cs, I wrote this:

```
  protected void btnImageSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageSearch();
}
private void ImageSearch()
{
    string ImageURL;
   ImageURL= Process.KeywordSearch(txtSearch.Text);
   Image1.ImageUrl = ImageURL;

}
```

and in my Process.cs, I wrote this:

```
public static string KeywordSearch(string keyword)
{
    string query = "SELECT imagepath FROM tbimage WHERE [title] = '" + keyword + "'";       

    return query;

}
```

After I wrote all these, I tried to debug. I typed in the keyword, but no image showed up.
I know in Process.cs, query will get the URL in database (the URL is like C:\ ....)
So Image1.ImageUrl should equal to that URL. but then I am wondering if

can this really get the Image1.ImageUrl? because no image showed up.

Hope somebody can help and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this you  can use `Image` control of asp.net and set its `ImageUrl` property to your image url. Like this

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

and in CodeBehind

```
Image1.ImageUrl = query;
```

Do as follow

> 1 Save or move your images into a
>   folder.
>  2 Add this folder into
>   your solution or project.
>  3 Take
>   image name only (not physical path)
>   from your database.
>  4  Set
>   ImageUrl property to virtual path.

Comment: Hey I followed what you said and got a problem. I edited the post to give more information what problem I have. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ric: remove `ImageUrl="Image1.ImageUrl"` that is wrong see my updated answer and then try and let me know.

Comment: one more thing you are using physical path but image control takes only virtual path.

Comment: ok so I took made 

string query = "SELECT picName FROM imagedatabase WHERE [keyword] = '" + keyword + "'";

but what is the meaning of virtual path?